# Madden sliders - how do they work?

Tags: madden-06, madden-07

I simulate all my games and just want to know how much the sliders in the game effect the outcome. In the game you can put the coaching sliders on aggressive or conservative. I haven't been able to tell if this truly changes anything.

Also on defense I need to know if conservative or aggressive would help give me more interceptions and sacks.

By the way this is for madden 06 and 07.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this has an impact on the play style in simulations.

Offense:

- go for it on 4th down instead of FG attempt and general behavior on 4th down
- go for 2 after a TD
- whether to go for a long pass
- run or pass in the red zone
- ...

Defense:

- penalty occurences
- fumble chance
- trade in interception chances for more completions

  - e.g. aggressive will lead to more INTs, but also weaker defense against running plays